# Cocoa-Touch - Chain animations together

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, animation, uipickerview

This probably sounds harder than it is. I'm actually trying to chain some animations together to make it look smooth. What I'm doing is some basic animation of a `UIPickerView` that slides from the bottom of the screen and when it is dismissed it slides back to the bottom of the screen. I handle this functionality in two methods `- (void)showPicker` and `- (void)hidePicker`

Directly after the picker has been hidden I want to show the keyboard, but I don't want to show the keyboard **before** the picker has been hidden.

Also I want to this the other way around, directly after the keyboard has been hidden I want to show the `UIPickerView`. I know I can observe notifications of `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardDidHideNotification`

So what would be the best way to deal with this so that these animations are chained together in a smooth way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the path picker->keyboard try

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                 animations:^{
                     [self hidePicker];
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     [yourInputView becomeFirstResponder];
                 }];
```

The other way around listen to UIKeyboardDidHideNotification and invoke `showPicker` in the callback.

Comment: I'm actually performing some more logic in hidePicker so it will be hidden before hidePicker returns.

Comment: Well then clearly you should put the actual hiding code into the animations block. Also you can play with the duration parameter...

Answer (score 0):

Do you show your picker as a way to input some info in a field or something?
If so, you better use the `inputView` property of `UITextField` so that it behaves quite like a normal TextField but uses your `UIPickerView` instead of the standard keyboard.

That's the standard way to do this (showing a picker in place of the keyboard) and you won't have to bother about chaining animations.

Comment: Nope, I have a `UITextField` (that uses the keyboard).

Comment: So that's it. If you have a `UITextField`, use the `inputView` property as explained to show the picker.

Comment: No no.. I have both a `UITextField` and a `UILabel` which I populate with data from the `UIPickerView`. Sorry for being unclear. I'm thinking I should maybe use blocks? Something like `- (void)showPickerCompletion:(void (^)completion)` (unsure of correct syntax)

Comment: Why not change your UILabel to a UITextField with the correct `inputView` property then? You can remove the frame around the UITextField to make it look like your label, and prevent copy/pasting it that UITextField and make the only possible input being your `UIPickerView`. That's what the `inputView` property is for.

Comment: Oops sorry once again. My UItextField Should get it's input from the keyboard and the UILabel should get it from the UIPickerView.

Comment: Yes I got it but replacing your `UILabel` by a read-only `UITextField` with no frame that looks the same would make it easier as the animation would be done automatically and the pseudo-label can become firstResponder, etc

Comment: But The user needs to input text through the keyboard.

Comment: ??? You don't get it. For those `UITextFields` in your interface which needs the keyboard, you keep them this way. For `UILabel` which values are set using a `UIPickerView`, remplace those `UILabels` with a `UITextField` and set those `UITextField`'s `inputView` property to a `UIPickerView`. There is no problem to have both some `UITextFields` with keyboard input and other `UITextFields` (formerly your `UILabels`) that use a `UIPickerView` as input!

Comment: Alright I'm with you.. but I don't understand how this will help me with the animations? Or will it be done "automagically" when I `resignFirstResponder` on the `UITextField`?

Comment: It will be done automatically, as any view set as the `inputView` of a `UITextField` will be displayed exactly as if it was the keyboard. So going from a `UITextField` with no `inputView` (= that shows the standard keyboard) to a `UITextField` whose `inputView` is a `UIPickerView` will automagically dismiss the real keyboard in a animated way and display the pickerview in an animated way too (with exactly the same animation as the one when the real keyboard itself is displayed).

Comment: And same thing in the opposite case of course: when you `resignFirstResponder` on your `UITextField`, the view serving as a keyboard will animate itself to disappear to the bottom, in the exact same maner whether it is the real iOS keyboard or your `UIPickerView`. The view used as the `inputView` property of a `UITextField` is really treated the same way (animations, firstResponder, etc) as if it was the real keyboard, that's the whole point of this property!

Comment: How do I make my read-only `UITextField` become first responder? If I set my textfield `userInteractionEnabled = NO` then it won't become first responder but if I set it to `YES` it will become first responder but then I will have a blinking cursor in there which I do not want. So how to make a read-only `UITextField` become first responder?